# Input validation won't prompt errors

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation, laravel

It seems like my validation won't work properly if I click the submit button it just refresh the browser and won't validate my inputs or I'm not sure if the Javascript cause the validation won't work. First I will start from appending my register form from other file using `empty()` and `append()` function based on user's option.

```
@section ('page-script')

<script>

    $(document).on("click", "#register", function ()
    {
        $.get("accountRegister", function (data)
        {
            $("#accountBottomContainer").empty();
            $("#accountBottomContainer").append(data);
        });
    });
 </script>

 @endsection
```

As you can see below here where I append **register.blade.php** in my `panel-body` named `#accountBottomContainer`

[image: Screenshot]

Here where I append my **register.blade.php** if the user hit the `register` button after the it wil append `panel-body` that has an `id = accountBottomContainer`

```
@section ('content')

<div class = "row">

    <div class = "col-xs-12 col-md-8">

        <div class = "panel panel-default">

            <div class = "panel-heading">

                <h2>Account Dashboard</h2>
                <hr>

            </div>

            <div class = "panel-body">

                <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-info" id = "register">Register Employee</button>
                <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-info" id = "searchEmployee">Search Employee</button>

                <div class = "row">
                <br>
                    <div class="col-md-10">

                        <div class = "panel panel-default">

                            <div class = "panel-body" style = "height: 500px" id = "accountBottomContainer">


                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div> 

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

@endsection

**Form with validation**

Here where I loop through each error to check where the user missed to fill up one of the textfields.

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)


<div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-md-6">
        <ul>
            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

@endif
<form class = "form-vertical" role = "form" method = "post" action = "{{ route ('account.accountRegister') }}">


    <div class = "form-group">

        <label for = "email" class = "control-label">Email Address</label>
        <input type = "text" name = "email" class = "form-control" id = "email">

    </div>

    <div class = "form-group">

        <label for = "username" class = "control-label">Username</label>
        <input type = "text" name = "username" class = "form-control" id = "username">

    </div>



    <div class = "form-group">

        <label for = "password" class = "control-label">Password</label>
        <input type = "password" name = "password" class = "form-control" id = "password">

    </div>

    <div class = "form-group">

        <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-default">Sign Up</button>

    </div>

    <input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = "{{ Session::token() }}">

</form>
```

**Controller**

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
                            //This will be unique in users table
        'email' => 'required|unique:users|email|max:255',
        'username' => 'required|unique:users|alpha_dash|max:20',
        'password' => 'required|min:6',
    ]);
 }
```

**routes**

```
Route::get('/accountRegister',
[
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\AccountController@getRegister',
    'as' => 'account.accountRegister',
]);

Route::post('/accountRegister', 
[
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\AccountController@postRegister',
]);
```

Comment: Consider not having spaces before and after the equal signs in your HTML attributes. It improves readability! (Note: This is not a solution to your question, simply a suggestion): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551541/using-spaces-before-and-after-the-sign-of-html-element-attribute

Answer (score 0):

On your javascript, you use a `#register` id, but i cannot see it on the html side. Is it a mistake?
You should rather use :

```
$(document).on("submit", "#theIdOfYourFormTag", function () {
```

Comment: Do you have a link so i can try?