# Webpage is zoomed on mobile screens

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

New to coding. I'm building a webpage with a basic game to learn HTML, Javascript, and CSS.
When I visit the site on my phone using Chrome, It's zoomed and only shows about 1/3rd of the screen zoomed into the top left.
I added a meta tag to set width=device-width and initial-scale = 1.0 after reading other questions on the same topic, but this still hasn't fixed my problem.
I added a snippet including all the code I thought was relevant.
This is my first question on stackoverflow, I'm desperate! 
Thanks

```css
body {
  min-width: 800px;
}

.topNav {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 5%;
  color: black;
}

.topNav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  float: right;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2.5em .5em;
}

.topNav a:hover {
  color: blue;
}

.topNav h1 {
  float: left;
}

.container {
  width = 100%;
}

*:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#breakoutCanvas {
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  background: #eee;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 25%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">

<head>
  <title>Games</title>
  <meta charset = "utf-8">
  <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/styleMain.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="breakout/breakout.css">
</head>

<body id = "gamesBody">

  <div class = "topNav" id = "indexTopNav">
    <h1 class = "pageHeaders" id = "gamesPageHeader">These are the games</h1>

    <a class = "navButton hvr-float-shadow" href = "../../index.html">Home</a>
    <a class = "navButton hvr-float-shadow" href = "../sports/sports.html">Sports</a>
    <a class = "navButton hvr-float-shadow" href = "../investing/investing.html">Investing</a>
    <a class = "active navButton hvr-float-shadow" href = "games.html">Games</a>
  </div>

  <div class = "container">
    <canvas id = "breakoutCanvas" width ="480" height="320"></canvas>
    <input type = "range" min = "2" max = "30" value = "10" class = "slider" id = "ballSizeSlider">
    <input type = "range" min = "1" max = "8" value = "3" class = "slider" id = "rowSlider">
  </div>

  <script src="breakout/breakout.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `body { min-width: 800px; }` <--- Think about what this is saying/doing.

Comment: Also, I've never seen spaces around the `=` in the `viewport` meta content.  I don't know if that's valid or not... it might be fine, but something to consider.

Comment: @Brad The spaces are not a problem.

Comment: body { min-width: 800px; } was posed as a possible solution in an article I read. With it removed, the full menu shows on the screen, but the canvas I'm using to draw the game on is still cut off

Comment: Still not working with body { width: 100%;}

Comment: Remove the width from both the body css and the container css. Add `overflow: scroll;` to the container class.

Comment: @KoshVery There is nothing in the spec that says you cannot have spaces around the `=`. It's not a problem to do this (although most people don't). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551541/using-spaces-before-and-after-the-sign-of-html-element-attribute

Comment: You shouldn't be specifying a `width` for the `body` at all.

Comment: Hey all, I set intial-scale to 0.25 in the HTML and it fixed the problem. Thanks for all of your time and help!

Comment: @camstar915 You didn't really *fix* your problem, you just added a potential new one to it that won't show up until later.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify width within style -> style = "width:100%" if you want to specify width inline with canvas tag otherwise specify width in #breakoutCanvas. FOr canvas 25% margin has been added in #breakoutCanvas is it required?

If you want to cover complete browser both in pc (where the resolution will be more than 1024px) and in mobile also you can specify width 100% to body as @Scott Marcus otherwise you can use max-width.

If you post wireframe about how you want the elements to be arranged can point out to right correction. (you can use paint to draw wireframe or any tools available online.)

Try to move all styling code to CSS.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.topNav {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 5%;
  color: black;
}

.topNav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  float: right;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2.5em .5em;
}

.topNav a:hover {
  color: blue;
}

.topNav h1 {
  float: left;
}

.container {
  width = 100%;
}

*:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#breakoutCanvas {
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  background: #eee;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">

<head>
  <title>Games</title>
  <meta charset = "utf-8">
  <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/styleMain.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="breakout/breakout.css">
</head>

<body id = "gamesBody">

  <div class = "topNav" id = "indexTopNav">
    <h1 class = "pageHeaders" id = "gamesPageHeader">These are the games</h1>

    <a class = "navButton hvr-float-shadow" href = "../../index.html">Home</a>
    <a class = "navButton hvr-float-shadow" href = "../sports/sports.html">Sports</a>
    <a class = "navButton hvr-float-shadow" href = "../investing/investing.html">Investing</a>
    <a class = "active navButton hvr-float-shadow" href = "games.html">Games</a>
  </div>

  <div class = "container">
    <canvas id = "breakoutCanvas" style =" width:100% "></canvas>
    <input type = "range" min = "2" max = "30" value = "10" class = "slider" id = "ballSizeSlider">
    <input type = "range" min = "1" max = "8" value = "3" class = "slider" id = "rowSlider">
  </div>

  <script src="breakout/breakout.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```